# How are these column vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the column vector is the column of numbers and that there are 5 of them in this example:

[image]

But I don't see how they are linearly independent (i.e. the only scalar solution is **0**),. What is going on here?

[image]

**Is this right?**

$$c1 * \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + c2 * \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + c4 * \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So if linearly independent than $$c_1v1 + c_2v2 + c_4v4 = (0,0,0)$$
So the set of equations that can be created is:

$$c_1 + 3c_3 + 3c_4 = 0$$
$$c_2 = 0$$
$$c_3 = 0$$

So the only solution for the scalars is trivial? Is this the right way to show linear independence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author tells you that $a_3 = -2 a_1 + a_2$ and $b_3 = -2 b_1 + b_2$ so $(a_1, a_2, a_3) $ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$  are linearly **dependent**.

However, $(b_1, b_2, b_4)$ are linearly **independent** as there doesn't exist $(\lambda, \mu, \rho)\neq 0_{\mathbb{R}^3}, \lambda b_1 + \mu b_2 + \rho b_3 = 0_{\mathbb{R}^5}$.

You can see it quickly by analysing the components of $b_1 = 1 e_1$, so $\lambda e_1 + 3 \mu e_1 + \mu e_2 + 3 \rho e_1 + \rho e_3=0$.

We can rewrite to be understood easier as : $(\lambda + 3\mu+3\rho,\mu,\rho,0,0)=(0,0,0,0,0)$

The component in front of $e_3$ must be zero, therefore $\rho = 0$. However, the component in front of $e_2$ must be zero $\mu = 0$. Finally, you need the component in front of $e_1$ to be zero, therefore $\lambda = 0$, so they are linearly independent.

Comment: I made an edit to my post... is it the same thing?

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes, you made the same thing as what I wrote.

Comment: @Jwan622 This is the right way to prove linear independance. There are harder ways, but you'll find out about it later.

Comment: Are b2 b3 and b4 linearly independent as well? What's a quick way to show this?

Comment: You wrote pb3, should it be pb4?

Comment: @Jwan622 Use the same method as I used. It's not really hard nor long.